# why sometimes the python interpreter can't recognize the up arrow key?

Tags: python

This question troubled me for really for a long time, and I can't figure out the answer all the time.

I have various versions of python in my ubuntu. Some versions of python's interpreter can 
recognize keyboard arrow keys normally. But some versions can't.

For example. In my python2.6 interpreter, all keyboard keys can be read properly. 
But in my python2.7 interpreter, if I type "up arrow key" on my keyboard, the interpreter will show this, what I want is to reappear `>>> test = "hello world"`:

```
(python2.7)yarkee@yarkee-laptop:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 19 2013, 19:57:37) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> test = "hello world"
>>> ^[[A
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like your python-2.6 interpreter was built with `readline` support, but your python-2.7 interpreter was not.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I use `pip install readline` to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Install [readline-devel](https://www.google.com/search?q=readline-devel&aq=0&oq=readline-&aqs=chrome.1.57j0l3j62l2.2940j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and recompile Python... Should fix the issue.